# Native SSL Support for WINAPI

Tags: c++, ssl, https, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to make a simple IRC client, using the Winsock API, to which I want to add SSL support. Currently I just use overlapped socket I/O like this:

```
SOCKET sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0x02, 0x01);

if (!sock)
    return;

struct sockaddr_in ircClient;

memcpy(&ircClient.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[0], he->h_length);
ircClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
ircClient.sin_port = wPort;

WSAEVENT hDataEvent = WSA_INVALID_EVENT;

if (WSAConnect(sock, (sockaddr*)&ircClient, sizeof(ircClient), 0, 0, 0, 0) > 0) {
    closesocket(sock);
    return;
}

if (wsWSAGetLastError() != 0) {
    closesocket(sock);
    return;
}
```

Now, as I understand, for SSL support, I need to do SSL handshake after `WSAConnect()`.  I found old Internet posts saying there are no SSL support in Winsock.  It is now is year 2017, and 95% of websites work with SSL.  Is there still no way to do this?  I have found [Using Secure Socket Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394814.aspx), but it is not SSL.

Comment: WinSock itself still does not support SSL, true. However, Microsoft's [SChannel API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx) does, and you can use your existing WinSock code for the I/O of SChannel-encrypted SSL data. See [Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374782.aspx). Otherwise, use a 3rd party SSL library. OpenSSL is very common, and it can be used on top of your existing WinSock code (via its `BIO` API). Or, you can re-write your code to let it handle all of the socket I/O for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done years ago some SSL/TLS stuff over standard TCP connections using native windows API, but I'm not familiar with this specific "secure socket extension".

I can recommend using SSPI. It doesn't automatically transform your socket to SSL, but can be used pretty easy for generating SSL request/response/data packets on request.
Look for `InitializeSecurityContext` for more info.